# Should I avoid using bold letters in question body?

Tags: support

I have seen many old and new posts on stackoverflow where posters use/used bold texts to discribe their problems or to greet other users " **Hello everyone!** " I have an old version of apache server. mod_rewrite is disabled. **How can I rewrite A to B?** I tried ..... but it returned **500** error.

What is The poster trying to get here?

A workin answer?

or

He wants to show readers what he has, how nice he writes, or perhaps he wants to get more attention of readers?

finally, Does it make sense to discribe my problem in bold letters? or should I avoid using bold letters in question body?

Comment: Sometimes I wish everyone with a 2 page question would bold the part **here is my question:** ... kinda reins it in, and reminds everyone that there is one

Comment: I think they are trying to get attention to their actual problem. However, it shouldn't be needed very often. I use it for separating sections of the post to make it easier to parse or possibly to highlight something that someone is inevitably going to ask otherwise. Such as something like, "this is **not** the same problem shown here <insert link to related but different post>".  But yes, you should avoid bolding too much.

Comment: @Drew It's far easier to just state the question at the very start, and at the very end, rather than burying it in the middle of the question where you make people feel like they need such a statement.

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit (said the most talkative character in the play).

Comment: Use them when they're appropriate.

Comment: The question here is sound.  I'm not sure why it's getting downvoted.  At least they're curious about this as opposed to going straight ahead and doing it anyway...

Answer (score 14):

Well obviously you're not prohibited from using them entirely.  The feature wouldn't be there if it was never appropriate to use them.

That said, you should use bold *very* sparingly.  Most cases where you just want to use a bit of additional emphasis on a word you can use *italics*, to emphasize the point in a less disruptive way.

But sometimes there is just something in a post that is *really* important, and you may feel that bolding that point is **essential** for the proper understanding of your post.

The problem of course is that the more content you bold (or italicize) the less it actually stands out.  You end up just removing all of the meaning of the formatting if you bold/italicize everything.

Another common trap is using bold text to try to mitigate the problem of a poorly structured post.  Different sections of a post stand out differently; and are more or less likely to be read.  If there's some point of your post that really is *super* important, it should probably be at the very start of your question, or at the very end of the post.  The essential point in any given paragraph should be in the opening or closing of that paragraph.

If the actual question of your post is half way through the 3rd paragraph (of 5) in your question then you might feel like you have to bold it for people to actually see it, but the much better way to make it stand out is to move it (or copy it) to the begging and/or end of your question, which people will typically look at first when first skimming the post.

So if you're using bold sparingly, and when it really is very important to emphasize that point, and there isn't a better way of ensuring that it stands out, then it's okay to use it.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any blanket rules to hold fast to here, but the main idea is that you want your question or answer to be **clear** and **concise**.  If text formatting conveys your point or tone clearer, then feel encouraged to use it.

What you want to *avoid* are scenarios in which the phrasing doesn't make sense.  Let's borrow your example.

> " **Hello everyone!** " I have an old version of apache server. mod_rewrite is disabled. **How can I rewrite A to B?** I tried ..... but it returned **500** error.

Leaving the grammar and sentence cadence aside, they're emphasizing junk.  The greeting needs to go, the question needs to be explicit, and the error being bold does them no favors.

It might read better thus:

> I have an old version of Apache server, and mod_rewrite is disabled. Without mod_rewrite, how can I rewrite URL A to URL B?  I tried this: `<insert attempt here>`, but when I do that, my server comes back with a 500 error.  What am I missing?

Notice that there is no bold in the above.  That's because the question doesn't call for it.  The OP is asking a plain and even-toned question; there's no nuance of conversation to be had.  They're just straight-up asking a question.

I will state that you most certainly *can* get someone's attention if you're using excessive style formatting...but it's almost never positive.