# Questions with a bounty but no answers can't be deleted, even after bounty has expired

Tags: discussion, support, bug, feature-request, bounty

**The Problem:**

I tried to delete a question I posted that had not received any answers and no longer seems relevant.  But the Stack Overflow software would not let me do so. (It says that is because I had offered a bounty, even though the bounty is now expired.)

**The Details:**

1. I posted a question ([Forge Reality Capture never starts
   processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70119653/forge-reality-capture-never-starts-processing)) that received no answers.
2. I added a bounty, because solving this problem promptly was time sensitive to me.
3. Even with the bounty this question still received zero answers.
4. Now, the bounty has expired, without an answer.
5. Stack Overflow is *sending me notifications* that now the bounty is passed, I need to award it to one of the answers.
6. Of course, with no answers at all, I can't choose any to give the award.
7. In addition, the time relevance of the question for me has also passed. Even a correct answer at this time would no longer help me.
8. And I suspect that the problem cited may no longer be repeatable, and so even a late answer would no longer be helpful to anyone else any more.

Given the question is now moot due to its time sensitivity, and lack of any answers, *it seems like the question itself is not worthy of keeping.*

So I tried to delete it.

But the Stack Overflow software won't permit deleting a question that had a bounty attached to it, even if that bounty has expired without ANY answers.

Does that seem like the right policy for authors deleting questions that have received no answers,  because an (unawarded) bounty existed?

Comment: On a stylistic note, the _sheer_ **amount** of _**formatting**_ used in your questions (both the main one and this meta) makes for a pretty distracting read. Some relevant meta discussions on this: [When is bolding considered unnecessary?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404403/11082165) and [Should I avoid using bold letters in question body?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311690/11082165)

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? The system will delete it automatically if it doesn't receive any answers

Comment: Eventually it'll be deleted. Better if you clean it up and self-answer it if you've come up with a good solution though. Avoid deleting unless the question is unfixable.

Comment: "*Even a correct answer at this time would no longer help me.*" I have to point out that you seem to be missing what SO *is*. The answers here are not *for you*. Yes, they answer your question but the point is to build up a repository of knowledge *for everyone*. If an answer *can be useful* then it shouldn't matter whether or not you personally benefit from it.

Comment: I'm confused. The timeline of the linked question says the bounty ended "35 mins ago". Yet this meta question was "asked 8 hours ago".

Comment: "Does that seem like the right policy for authors deleting questions that have received no answers, because an (unawarded) bounty existed?" - I would be perfectly fine with question author's being unable to delete their contributions without the community agreeing with the deletion. Questions being deleted because they get a couple downvotes, is far to common, sometimes questions are even deleted once they get an answer.  Unlike Eric Cartman and his ball, you don't get to take your ball and go home, once you have submitted your question it's communities ball.

Comment: Note that deleted posts still count toward potential bans. With over a thousand reputation, I hope you're far away from such worries, but I've seen too many thinking removing the stain of a poorly-received post with deletion is a better choice than fixing up the post  and suffering because of it.

Comment: I agree with VLAZ, the merit of whether t keeping the post in SO should not be whether it answers MY questions,  but rather whether it could ever assist in answering ANY future reader’s questions.   

The problem of no answers at all is that the question I posed is why is my code that was working before no longer working, and what information in the diagnostics provides information on why it failed.

Comment: The problem of no answers at all is that the question I posed is “why is this code that was working before no longer working, and what information in the diagnostics provides information on why it failed?” If there is no information in the code to answer that question, and no information in the diagnostics,  and no answers explaining what went wrong and how to correct it in the future, it is just an announcement of an unexplained one time event.

Comment: I was worrying that future readers may be tempted by a search engine to waste their precious time reading a long data filled post for zero information.  That outcome, that the original post would waste even future SO users time was what motivated me to think the question itself should be deleted if unanswerable.  But I am content leaving it if others think the data in it can provide some value, even without a resolution.

Answer (score 7):

The bounty expired, but that doesn't meant the bounty is complete. It just means no more answers can benefit from the bounty. You, however, get time to award the bounty to the (yes, nonexistent) answer(s). As [the documentation says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), "After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty."

So you have to wait 24 hours after the expiration of the bounty before you'll be able to delete the question, if indeed that is what you choose to do.